# HeidiSQL rounds down double values upon insert...select

Tags: mariadb, select, insert, temporary-tables, floating-point

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `new_aps` (
  `MinuteStart` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ProxyListID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `SuccessCount` double(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `UnknownCount` double(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `FailureCount` double(22,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProxyListID`,`MinuteStart`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

When I try to run the following query in HeidiSQL:

```
INSERT INTO new_aps (MinuteStart, ProxyListID, SuccessCount, UnknownCount, FailureCount)
SELECT NOW(), 1, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5
```

I get the following entry in `new_aps` table:

```
SELECT * FROM new_aps
"2020-06-11 11:58:19"   "1" "0" "1" "2"
```

What am I doing wrong? I need double-precision floating-point values stored in the table.

MariaDB version is 10.4.13 on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: "Counts", to me mean integral values.  Use an integer type?

Comment: @RickJames, no, they are not integers because they are divided by the number of lists a proxy belongs to. You can rather suggest a better name for such amounts :) .

Comment: "Rate", "Ratio", "PerList".  Maybe "Percent" or "Pct", but that might mean throwing a factor of 100.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently HeidiSQL corrupts the table creation code. The proper table creation code is (without bounds after `double`):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `new_aps` (
  `MinuteStart` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ProxyListID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `SuccessCount` double NOT NULL,
  `UnknownCount` double NOT NULL,
  `FailureCount` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProxyListID`,`MinuteStart`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And the proper way to get it is from the database server, rather than HeidiSQL client:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE new_aps
```